# How to Properly style TabView Bar?

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabview

In Swift 5.8.1

I'm trying to add style to my TabView bar in my "MainView" file in my project. But I don't see a way to add an image or effect that would then carry across to all my other views.

I want the TabView to be invisible but then use this code

```
struct FrostedGlassView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIVisualEffectView {
        UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .systemUltraThinMaterial))
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVisualEffectView, context: Context) {}
}
```

to add the glass effect to it so content behind it has that effect covering it. In my method I add the glass to each view. Is that the best / only option? or can I add it to my MainView TabView and have it in each view?

I also need to know the size of the bar since the code below I just guess the size

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("BackgroundImage")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                FrostedGlassView()
                    .overlay(Color.black.opacity(0.0))
                    .frame(height: 90)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.horizontal)
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Solution to add a Frosted Glass effect but then I'd need to add this to each view. is that the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly u want to have blur effect on bottom toolbar.

```swift
enum SelectionCase {
    case home1
    case home2
    case home3
    case home4
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection : SelectionCase = .home1
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            CustomTabView(selection: $selection) {
                ScrollView {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.red)
                        .frame(height: 1200)
                }
                .tag(SelectionCase.home1)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.yellow)
                    .tag(SelectionCase.home2)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.mint)
                    .tag(SelectionCase.home3)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.cyan)
                    .tag(SelectionCase.home4)
            }
            TabBar(selection: $selection)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct CustomTabView<T : View, R : Hashable>: View {
    @Binding var selection : R
    @ViewBuilder var content : () -> T
    var body: some View {
            TabView(selection: $selection) {
                content()
                    .gesture(DragGesture())
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
    }
}



struct TabBar: View {
    @Binding var selection : SelectionCase
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "house")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .onTapGesture {
                  
                }
            Image(systemName: "house")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .onTapGesture {
                    selection = .home2
                }
            Image(systemName: "house")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .onTapGesture {
                    selection = .home3
                }
            Image(systemName: "house")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .onTapGesture {
                    selection = .home4
                }
                
        }
        .padding(.vertical,30)
        .background {
            FrostedGlassView()
        }
    }
}



struct FrostedGlassView : UIViewRepresentable {
   
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIVisualEffectView {
        return UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .regular))
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVisualEffectView, context: Context) { }
}
```

[image: Show case]